# Careers /send-message POST is 404ing

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I can't reply to messages, or use the "interested" or "not interested" buttons. I get the error: "Sending message failed. Please reload and try again. (click to dismiss)".

It looks like all my POSTS to `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages/send-message/123456` are returning 404s.

Comment: Any chance you got logged out?

Comment: Still logged in. I refreshed the page, have the navbar with my picture on it.

Comment: Same here, exactly as @JoeFrambach described. I too am still logged in.

Comment: Hey all, am looking into this now. I'll answer once it's fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should now be fixed. Please let me know if you are still having problems replying. Apologies for the inconvenience.